# Specifying Pipeline resource version using variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When using Pipeline resource an error occurs when I am trying to use the value of the Version field as a variable value.

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: BuildApp
    source: BuildApp
    # version: $(appversion) <- this doesn't work
    version: 20191204.17  <- this works
```

Static version looks not so useful. Is it possible to specify such version for each run dynamically? 
For example, using variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion is resolved:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/845445/pipeline-resource-version-property-as-a-variable-1.html

Microsoft's answer:
While we can’t allow variables in that field, this is an excellent use case for [runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

I tested and reproduced the problem you met and use parameters, template variable, template parameter or template will make no change, it keeps throwing error messages.

I think you can only use predefined variables here according to this thread: [Is it possible to use a variable in the ref property of resources:repository for Azure DevOps YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56794984/is-it-possible-to-use-a-variable-in-the-ref-property-of-resourcesrepository-for).

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Comment: Thanks, the suggestion was posted https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/845445/pipeline-resource-version-property-as-a-variable-1.html